# How can I fetch my Facebook status (online or not) and manipulate it in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, chat, status

I'd like to display my chat status on my website, so I can tell my customers they can reach my through Facebook chat. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are going with this.  Do you just need read permissions so that you can display stuff on your website?  Or do you want implement chat functionality on your website so that your customers can chat to you on Facebook through your website?  Have you looked through the Facebook API docs yet?  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this link:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/status.get/
or search on "make an FQL query (fql.query) on the status (FQL) table", taken from that same link, which should do you nicely.

I guess you could make a PHP script that uses the status.get or fql.query (on status table) to pull your status on page load. Maybe place it in the header/footer that is shared across your site. This way as soon a someone comes to your page they'll see your current FB status.

Comment: Actually, what I want to get is my _chat_ status. That is, if I'm online or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? Customers can't even use the chat if they aren't friend with you ?
Just create an anchor from your facebook profile page

Comment: What do you mean an anchor? And anyway, I thought of something like : "Friend us on Facebook and get live support".

Comment: @Neuschwanstein look at the @thescientist 's response, everything you should know about facebook integrity is to be found there.